# Spring Boot Batch: How to implement a multithreaded step with CompositeWriter and custom ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a batch application which read from a table and use two writers with CompositeItemWriter. One writer calls a SOAP api to delete the user and the second Writer update the status in the same table which it red form once the API call is successful. If the user is already in delete status the API will throw error. I have updated the the table with valid data so it read accurately but the issue is with the writer which calls the API. I see that each chunk one record is called twice as a result it throws an error and never update the status of that record in the second writer. I have a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor with setConcurrencyLimit(5). And I am using JdbcPagingItemReader for reader. I think my ItemWriter implementation is not thread safe or I am doing something else wrong. Its a Production scenario and unfortunately I wont be able to share exact code but I did replicate that personally. Here is my code;

**BatchConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
        
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("user_purge");
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }
    
    //JOB: Soft Delete
    @Bean
    public Job softDeleteJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("softDeleteJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(softDeleteStep())
                .listener(new JobLoggerListener())
                .build();
    }
    
    
    //STEP: SOFT DELETE
    @Bean
    public Step softDeleteStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("softDeleteStep")
                .<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(5)
                .reader(softDelReader())
                .writer(compositeSoftDelWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                //.skipLimit(100000)
                //.skip(Exception.class)
                //.noRetry(Exception.class)
                //.noRollback(Exception.class)                 
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<UserInfo> softDelReader() {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<UserInfo> pagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

        pagingItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        pagingItemReader.setFetchSize(3);
        pagingItemReader.setRowMapper(new SoftDeleteMapper());

        MySqlPagingQueryProvider mySqlPagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT user_id, user_status");
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM db3.user_purge");
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause( "WHERE user_status = 'I' "
                                                    + "AND purge_status = 'N'");

        Map<String, Order> orderByKeys = new HashMap<>();
        orderByKeys.put("user_id", Order.ASCENDING);

        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(orderByKeys);
        pagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(mySqlPagingQueryProvider);

        return pagingItemReader;
    }    
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositeSoftDelWriter() {
        CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(userInfoApiWriter(), softDelPurgeWriter()));
        return compositeItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public UserInfoWriter userInfoApiWriter() {
        return new UserInfoWriter();
    }
            
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> softDelPurgeWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        writer.setSql("UPDATE db3.user_purge SET purge_status = 'S', soft_del_date = NOW() WHERE user_id = :userId");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }   
}
```

Thought skip, noRetry or noRollback may help but it did not

**UserInfoWriter.class: Custom ItemWriter for API calls**

```
public class UserInfoWriter implements ItemWriter<UserInfo> {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserInfoWriter.class);

    
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends UserInfo> items) throws Exception {
                    
        for(UserInfo item: items) {
            // Calling the SOAP api with item.getUserId()
        };
    }
}
```

As I mentioned I could see that one record is called twice in each chunk. Seems like two different thread is picking up same record. I could see sometimes its more than a record. A help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I have updated the code with SynchronizedItemStreamReader and SynchronizedItemStreamWriter hoping this may solve my threading issue. But I think my CompositeItemWriter implementaion is not right I am getting an error - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A delegate item writer is required" Here is my updated step, readers and writers

```
@Bean
    public Step softDeleteStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("softDeleteStep")
                .<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(100)
                .listener(new StepWriteListener())
                .reader(softDelReader())                
                .processor(softDeleteProcessor())
                .writer(compositeSoftDelWriter())
//                .stream(softDeleteApiWriter())
                .listener(new StepStartStopListener())       
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(40)                
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<UserInfo> softDelReader() {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<UserInfo> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(3);
        reader.setSaveState(false);
        reader.setRowMapper(new SoftDeleteMapper());

        MySqlPagingQueryProvider mySqlPagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT user_id, user_status");
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM db3.user_purge");
        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause( "WHERE user_status = 'I' "
                                                    + "AND purge_status = 'N'");

        Map<String, Order> orderByKeys = new HashMap<>();
        orderByKeys.put("user_id", Order.ASCENDING);

        mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(orderByKeys);
        reader.setQueryProvider(mySqlPagingQueryProvider);

        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<UserInfo> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(reader);
        
        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public SoftDeleteItemProcessor softDeleteProcessor() {
        return new SoftDeleteItemProcessor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositeSoftDelWriter() {
        CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(softDeleteApiWriter(), softDelTableWriter()));
        
        return compositeItemWriter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public UserInfoApiWriter softDeleteApiWriter() {
        return new UserInfoApiWriter();
    }   
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> softDelTableWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        writer.setSql("UPDATE db3.user_purge SET purge_status = 'S', "
                + "soft_del_date = NOW() WHERE user_id = :userId");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }
```

Writer implementation

```
public class UserInfoApiWriter extends SynchronizedItemStreamWriter <UserInfo> {
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void write(List<? extends UserInfo> items) throws Exception {
        for(UserInfo item: items) {         
            
            //API call
            
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks a bit odd that you are calling @Bean annotated methods directly instead of letting spring inject the values.

Comment: @tgdavies it looks odd but works, there is no issue with that. I suspect that your issue is with your reader, also why throw an error if the status is already deleted? This will actually break your batch processing if you haven't correctly configured skipping and retrying.

Comment: @M.Deinum, we dont have control over API. Its just like that if the status is updated in the API already it will throw error. But there is no chance that error will occur as I am processing only those record which are never been updated there. But its throwing error due to the fact that somehow the same record is called twice in the UserInfoWriter. I don't know why the multiple threads are taking the same record.

Comment: @M.Deinum so those calls will get proxies which will do the scopes correctly?

Comment: @tgdavies yes. That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Thomson if the same record is processed twice this is generally an issue in the reader **not** the writer. You are updating the same set of records you are reading, so if you haven't properly written the query it will re-read the same records.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, I have had that *not* happen in older versions of Spring, and under different circumstances (not using @Configuration)

Comment: Using `@Configuration` is a requirement, with a regular `@Component` it won't work (which is also documented in the Spring Reference Guide).

Comment: Have you tried to decorate your `JdbcPagingItemReader` with a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, do you think I still need to use JdbcPagingItemReader or can I just use JdbcCursorItemReader ?

Comment: `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread-safe while the `JdbcPagingItemReader` is.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine: I tried to implement the Reader as you suggested but it is not executing. I think I am doing it wrong. I would also like to know how to extend SynchronizedItemStreamWriter into my writer class but I am so confused about its implementation.